# Un sólo login para acceder a dos sistemas PHP y c#

Tags: php, c#, laravel, asp.net-mvc-5, login

Actualmente estoy desarrollando un sistema.

Inicialmente el sistema lo estaba desarrollando en PHP- Laravel, pero por
decisiones de la persona a cargo se decidió que debería implementarse en
Asp.Net MVC 5 - c#.
En el código php ya esta avanzado el tema del control de accesos y configuraciones en general, es por eso que esa parte se decidió mantener.

Mi problema es, ¿Cómo podría incorporar un solo logín para acceder a ambos sistemas?
Consejos por favor. Gracias.

Comment: Van a mezclar dos lenguajes de back end distintos? no suena a una sabia decision. Mas alla de eso, a que te refieres con mezclar? como es el sistema de logueo? usas cookies? tokens? ademas algunas paginas van a ser server rendering (las php) y despues van a cambiar de tecnologia a las asp?

Comment: Lo que necesito es que, al ingresar al programa en php, ya no sea necesario, loguearse en mvc 5,  compartir sesiones entre ellas, ¿Es posible? ¿Cómo lo podria hacer?

Comment: Sería una muy mala práctica tener PHP y MVC.Net en una sola aplicación. Pero si de todas formas decides hacerlo puedes leer el siguiente artículo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544389/how-to-share-sessions-between-php-and-asp-net-application

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un token para hacer un autologeo entre aplicaciones.

Dentro del token podrías utilizar caducidad y las credenciales del usuario para validar su correcto acceso.

Te dejo un poco sobre la encriptación AES(Advanced Encryption Standard) y la comunicación entre PHP y C#:

https://www.japicoder.es/articulos/cifrado-y-descifrado-con-aes-128-entre-php-y-net